# How to call Scala method in Java class

Tags: java, scala, playframework-2.0

As I need that Play application should load and read a single message file, I was thinking of calling `loadMessages()` method of `MessagesPlugin` class of Scala from my `Application` class of Java and pass the path of single message file. I am assuming that when my application will boot , it will call `loadMessages()` method of Scala and create map of single message file. Kindly rectify if my understanding is wrong.

As I am totally new to Scala programming , kindly rectify me If I am calling Scala method in Java class in wrong way:

```
import play.api.i18n.MessagesPlugin;
class Application{
      private static boolean renderHomePage(){
        language="en";        
        String configPath=System.getProperty("IUI_CONFIG_DIR");
        MessagesPlugin.loadMessages(configPath+"/"+language+"/messages."+language);
        changeLang(language);       
        setSessionData(true);
        return true;
    }
}
```

But my above code is unable to recognize `loadMessages()`. Do I need to import something else.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you can see [here](https://github.com/playframework/playframework/blob/master/framework/src/play/src/main/scala/play/api/i18n/Messages.scala), loadMessages is protected. You have to extend MessagesPlugin to be able to call that method.

Comment: In your link , method is shown as protected and in this [link](https://github.com/playframework/playframework/blob/2.0.x/framework/src/play/src/main/scala/play/api/i18n/Messages.scala) loadMessages method is private.So which one I should refer.

Comment: Depends on your version. My link is from master (newest version), yours is from version 2.0.

Comment: I am using 2.1.3 version of play in my project and in that loadMessages method is private. Can we override private method of scala in java?If yes , any link or example will be highly useful.